# What are the consequences of sexting with minors overseas?

Tags: minor, sexual-assault

Suppose a 15 year old sexts an adult(lets say an 18 year old) first. They engage in conversation and share nudes back and forth. This happens for about a year or so. What consequences/charges do the adult and the minor have to face in this case? They are from different country and it was, say, minor's parents who filed the case.

Answer (score 2):

### It really makes no difference that the  people are in different countries

Each will be prosecuted according to the laws of the country they are in and, if they are citizens of country(s) that claim extraterritorial jurisdiction over these crimes, of the country(s) they are citizens of.